# Lightbox Window Not Popping Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

http://brightpixelstudios.co.uk/portfolio/

When I click on the thumbnail to start a pop up window, the window doesn't appear as it should and there's a weird couple of 'next' and 'previous' links appearing in the bottom left of the screen.

It was working a month ago when I last checked. Is there anything in the code I can do to fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Regards, Will

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your html code for css references, right now it looks like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id=  href='http://brightpixelstudios.co.uk/ext/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id=  href='http://brightpixelstudios.co.uk/ext/wp-pagenavi/pagenavi-css.css?ver=2.70' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id=  href='http://brightpixelstudios.co.uk/skin/02/includes/css/prettyPhoto.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

which is wrong remove that id=

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated! Now I need to find where I can edit the HTML on wordpress..

Comment: go to wp-content/themes/[Your Theme]/header.php, you will find the code if you have added it manually